# E: Sub process returned an error code

Tags: pycharm, idle-python

I am trying to install pycharm in ubuntu 16.04. but when I ran this command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make`, 
after some processing in terminal the system stops workind and showed this message

```
E: Sub process returns an error code.
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to install ubuntu-make without adding a ppa, run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install ubuntu-make
```

In order to quickly and easily install PyCharm Community Edition in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install --classic pycharm-community
```

This command will install a standalone PyCharm snap package which does not depend on ubuntu-make.

Comment: Again error! But this time this one:
 Unknown flag  'classic'

Comment: classic must be preceded by 2 hyphen characters, like this `--classic` Run the command `man snap` and scroll down to the `install` section to read the `--classic` usage.

Comment: Sir i did same as u mentioned. but still system is committing error